# Polarization of light using Mueller matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I would like to ask about Mueller matrix operation and stokes parameter.
Given the Mueller matrix:

[image]

The input of light state is:

[image]

And lastly, the operation to produce the output of light after it go through a half wave plate:

[image]

After I do the calculation, the S_out for the θx=0° is [1 1 0 0] meaning that the light is horizontally polarized. However, when the θx=45°, I didn't get the vertical light polarization [1 -1 0 0] as stated in wikipedia:

[image]

This is my python code to produce the result:

```
y=0
M_HWP=np.matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, math.cos(4*y), math.sin(4*y), 0], [0, 
      math.sin(4*y), -(math.cos(4*y)), 0], [0, 0, 0, -1]])
z=45
M_HWP2=np.matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, math.cos(4*z), math.sin(4*z), 0], [0, 
      math.sin(4*z), -(math.cos(4*z)), 0], [0, 0, 0, -1]])

S_in=np.matrix('1 ;1 ;0 ;0')
print ("S_in\n",S_in)

Zerodeg=M_HWP*S_in
print("Horizontal polarized \n",Zerodeg)
fourtyfivedeg=np.rint(M_HWP2*S_in)
print("Vertically polarized \n",fourtyfivedeg)
```

This is the result of my calculation using Python programming language:

[image]

It seems that my vertical polarization of light is wrong. I hope that anyone may help me to clarify this problem.
Thank you so much & regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`math.sin()` and `math.cos()` work with radians, not degrees, so you should convert the angles first:

```
y=math.radians(0)
M_HWP=np.matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, math.cos(4*y), math.sin(4*y), 0], [0,
      math.sin(4*y), -(math.cos(4*y)), 0], [0, 0, 0, -1]])
z=math.radians(45)
M_HWP2=np.matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, math.cos(4*z), math.sin(4*z), 0], [0,
      math.sin(4*z), -(math.cos(4*z)), 0], [0, 0, 0, -1]])

S_in=np.matrix('1 ;1 ;0 ;0')
print ("S_in\n",S_in)

Zerodeg=M_HWP*S_in
print("Horizontal polarized \n",Zerodeg)
fourtyfivedeg=np.rint(M_HWP2*S_in)
print("Vertically polarized \n",fourtyfivedeg)
```

I would also suggest a little different implementation, if you like:

```
 import numpy as np
 import math

def polar(I,angle):
    M = np.array([
        [1,0,0,0],
        [0,math.cos(4*math.radians(angle)),math.sin(4*math.radians(angle)),0],
        [0, math.sin(4 * math.radians(angle)), -math.cos(4 * math.radians(angle)), 0],
        [0,0,0,-1]
    ])

    return np.matmul(M,I)

I = [[1.0],[1.0],[0.0],[0.0]]

print(polar(I,0))
print(polar(I,45))
```

Output:

> [[1.]  [1.]  [0.]  [0.]]
>
> [[ 1.0000000e+00]  [-1.0000000e+00]  [ 1.2246468e-16]  [
>   0.0000000e+00]]

You can see 1.2246468e-16 because of of conversion from degrees to radians, which is ~0

Comment: Alright, I will put `print(np.rint(polar(I,45)))` to make 1.2246468e-16 become 0.